# reflection get and set String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

I want to trim any class String fields using reflection but I encounter with this exception when I was running th program :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: BeanX.setName()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
at Test.trimStr(Test.java:19)
at Test.main(Test.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

here is my POJO `BeanX` data container:

```
public class BeanX {

    private String name;

    private String fname;

    private long age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and here is my test class and my fancy method but I don't know why that exception occurs:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {
    public  <T> T trimStr(T t) throws Exception{
        Class clazz = t.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        Method unknownMethod;
        for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i].getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
                String fieldName = fields[i].getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fields[i].getName().substring(1);
                unknownMethod = clazz.getMethod("get"+fieldName);
                String strValue = unknownMethod.invoke(t).toString();

                unknownMethod = clazz.getMethod("set"+fieldName);
                String newValue = strValue.trim();
                unknownMethod.invoke(t, new String(strValue.trim()));
            }
        }
     return t;
    }


    public static void main(String ... args)throws Exception{
        BeanX x = new BeanX();

        x.setAge(2L);
        x.setName("John   ");
        x.setFname("   X");
        System.out.println(x.getName()+";");
        Test tee = new Test();
        BeanX y = tee.trimStr(x);
        System.out.println(y.getName()+";");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `getMethod`? What arguments does it take?

Comment: the problem is setMethod not getMethod

Comment: Your stacktrace shows otherwise `at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)`

Comment: There is no `setMethod`. I don't mean getters and setters.

Comment: if I print strValue I will get the name "John   "

Comment: Also, the exception isn't stupid. It's there to tell you you are doing something wrong. Read the javadoc.

Comment: getMethod is a "Class object method" in reflection man, please don't confuse me ...

Comment: Right, and the exception occurs there, as shown in the stacktrace. You're invoking the method with a single argument. What do you think that does? Why do you think so?

Comment: When working with Beans consider to use java.beans.Introspector and get the read/ write method from the PropertyDescriptor.

Comment: take a look at my BeanX class the setName is right there with an String argument, I believe this exception is wrong because everything is correct. u check it in your machine I even get the value of name when I call getName method using reflection ;)

Comment: **Never** assume you are correct when dealing with an established language. And everything is **not** correct. You are using the `Class#getMethod(..)` incorrectly as shown in Boris' answer below.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry GUYS :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You issue is here:

```
clazz.getMethod("set"+fieldName);
```

From the [JavaDoc for `Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> public Method getMethod(String name,
>                  Class... parameterTypes)
>                    throws NoSuchMethodException,
>                           SecurityException
>
> Returns a Method object that reflects the 
>   specified public member method of the class or interface
>   represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String
>   specifying the simple name of the desired method. The parameterTypes
>   parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's
>   formal parameter types, in declared order. If parameterTypes is null,
>   it is treated as if it were an empty array.

You have passed in **no arguments** so it is looking for a method that takes no arguments.

Presumably your `setter` would take a `String` argument:

```
clazz.getMethod("set"+fieldName, String.class);
```

Comment: thanx, my mistake - My eyes really didn't see that small ridiculous part after 18 hours coding .. thank you mate

Comment: @JohnX after _only_ 18 hours? Isn't that a standard shift in the programming world?

Comment: I think the standard is 8 hours, so 10 hours overhead ... I'm trying to resurrect a dead project and I'm working freelance and at home. how much hours you guys work on a code per day ?